# git show file with rename detection (equivalent to git log --follow)

Tags: git, rename

I want to see the content of a file which was renamed in the past in a commit state before the rename was done (with automatic detection of course).

With `git log --follow foo_renamed.txt` and `git show master~20 foo_original_name.txt` I can confirm that git is able to track the file rename and the file is present in `master~20`. However,

```
git show --follow master~20:foo_renamed.txt
```

and

```
git show -M master~20:foo_renamed.txt
```

both fail with

> fatal: Path 'foo_renamed.txt' exists on disk, but not in 'master~20'.

This actually makes sense because the object specification is a `<rev>:<path>` blob but there is no `-- /file/path` option for `git show`. Any other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.  Only `git log --follow` implements the special case hack to track these kinds of detected renames (they have to be detected, one commit at a time, while working back through history), and it does so with code that is not very well suited to this task.

It should be possible, if you want to work on Git, to modify the code to make it more flexible, and add an option to `git show` where you give `git show` the ID of a commit that is a descendant of the target commit, but *does* have the file.  Git would then have to walk revisions, the way `git log` does, doing the rename detection (but with this more flexible code), so that when the commit-graph walk reaches the commit to be shown, Git would be able to use the earlier name.

The invocation might be something like:

```
git show --follow[=<start>] commit -- path
```

where `<start>` defaults to `HEAD`.  This is a nontrivial thing to write, though.

(Also, `git show` *should* reject `--follow` right now; the fact that it allows it at all is a minor bug.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe if torek says `git show` can't do this right now that's the current situation.

My workaround for now is:

```
git show master~42:`git log --follow master~42..master \
--name-only --oneline -- path/to/file | tail -n1`
```